# Create Hook Failed: Invalid Header

Tags: asp-classic, jscript, bigcommerce

```
createHook: function(scope,callback_url) {
    http.open("POST","https://api.bigcommerce.com/"+this.context+"/v2/hooks",false);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    http.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    http.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Client",this.client_id);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token",this.access_token);
    http.send(JSON.stringify({
      scope: scope,
      destination: callback_url,
      is_active: true
    }));
}
```

This attempt returns status code 400 with a JSON object with error set to "Invalid Header."

Any of the other API functions including listing hooks (GET /hooks) is successful.

Comment: You've tagged this as classic asp.  It this js supposed to run client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting same error, After adding `"X-Custom-Auth-Header": "{secret_auth_password}"` it creates successfull. returs 201 code.